# Simple Questions/Answer Games

Tags: javascript, html

My project is a simple game.
You press [START]
You hear a "random" word
You have a type-in box,
if you fill it right you get +5 points and get a random word .... and so on.
You fill it wrong, you lose immediately [gameover]

Although, I would deeply appreciate to code the whole game, for some of you it is relatively simple - I wish to do it myself for the learning experience and sense of accomplishment!

For now, I only need a push in the right direction.
I aim to use it on my tablet or phone (both run Android)

Comment: What about those who don't know how to code and are just asking for directions?

Comment: "I wish to do it myself for the learning experience and sense of accomplishment!

For now, I only need a push in the right direction. I aim to use it on my tablet or phone (both run android)"

Comment: I only need an answer for what language I ought to learn based on my idea...
I never implied that I want a code writing service!

Comment: A simple answer, even one word is fine!

Comment: You can use w3cschools.com for easy to understand js tutorials and explanations. https://www.w3schools.com/js/ Try reading through it and you will be able to start your own projects. Stackoverflow is only for precise problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by learning the fundamentals of JavaScript and HTML (should also learn CSS if you want the app to look nice). There are many sites (other than SO) that have multiple tutorials and/or full documentation (i.e. MDN, W3Schools). You could also use online teaching platforms for that.

Here are a couple of things you should consider after getting a grasp of the basic concepts:

- When do you want to check if the user inserted the right input (timer, on enter, a submit button)?
- Where will the sounds be stored and how will you retrieve them (a collection of sounds of files, a database with a server, a single big sound file containing all of the words)?
- Regardless of how you store the sounds you will need a way to map text to the sound and the random number (`Math.random()`) to one of the two.
- Finally create a JavaScript function that resets the text and gets a new word every time the user gets the word right or when the initial start button is clicked.

Once you reach any questions on the actual coding, search for the problem in SO (odds are it has been asked before). If you can't find an answer to your question create a new question.